# integration test for http handler current request server variables

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I would need to write an integration test for the method in the Data Access Layer which has got HttpHandler.Current.Request server variables. It is throwing the error 'object reference not set to an instance of the object. Can we do integration test for HttpHandler.Current.Request server variables?

Implementation:

```
public SubmissionHeaderDTO GetRefNo(VariablesDTO requestVariables)
        {
            using(var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.DBConnection))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();                
                    using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("usp_testInsert", sqlConn))
                    {
                        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = requestVariables.Id;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FormCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = requestVariables.Prefix;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@FormTitle", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = requestVariables.Title;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = requestVariables.User;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Url", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = requestVariables.Url;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Host", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = requestVariables.RemoteHostName;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@RemoteHost", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = requestVariables.RemoteHost;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserAgent", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = requestVariables.UserAgent;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Referrer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = requestVariables.HttpReferrer;
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ClosingCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = requestVariables.Code;

                        SqlParameter outputSubmissionId = new SqlParameter("@SubmissionId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
                        {
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                        };

                        SqlParameter outputSubmissionSequence = new SqlParameter("@SubmitSequence", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30)
                        {
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                        };

                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(outputSubmissionId);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(outputSubmissionSequence);

                        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        var submissionHeaderDto = new SubmissionHeaderDTO()
                        {
                            SubmissionId = (Guid)outputSubmissionId.Value,
                            SubmitSequence = outputSubmissionSequence.Value.ToString()
                        };
                        return submissionHeaderDto;

                    }
            }

        }
```

My DTO is as below:

```
public class VariablesDTO
    {
        public string Prefix { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string User { get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; } }

        public string Url { get { return HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.Handler == null ? null : HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri; } }

        public string UserAgent { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]; } }

        public string HttpReferrer { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]; } }

        public string RemoteHost { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]; } }

        public string RemoteHostName { get { return System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName; } }
    }
```

Integration Test below is throwing an error with 'object reference not set to an instance of an object for http server variables in the DTO.

```
var variablesDTO = new VariablesDTO();
            VariablesDTO.Code = "ABC";
            VariablesDTO.Prefix = "DEF";
            VariablesDTO.Title = "Test form";
            VariablesDTO.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            var submitSequence = "DEF-1";
            //act
            var results = this._formDataService.GetRefNo(variablesDTO);

            //assert            
            Assert.AreEqual(submitSequence, results.SubmitSequence);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your dto dependent on other objects like HttpContext.  The whole point of a dto is to be a lightweight data transfer mechanism.  These should have only getters and setters to its own internal state.  Take the information from the HttpContext and copy it into the dto.  Your other issue is that your are dependent on HttpContext.Current which is a static call and isn't easily mocked for unit testing.  You might consider hiding that behind an interface so you can mock that as well.

Comment: I need all the properties for passing into the GetRefNo method, if I exclude  from the DTO, should I need to create another class for httpcontext properties? and then I would need to pass in the DTO and the class of httpcontext to the GetRefNo method. How do I hide behind an interface to mock it?

Comment: no, don't exclude the properties them from the DTO, have them implemented as just {get;set;} and set the values from the HttpContext.Current.

Comment: if you are looking to decouple from HttpContext.Current, you can always put an interface in front of it.  something like IProvideCurrentHttpContext.  then just have the implementation return HttpContext.Current.  Now you can mock/fake that dependency.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I didn't get quite right. If I just implement as {get; set;}, where do I set the values for it? What will be in the IProvideCurrentHttpContext?

Comment: Set the values wherever you are instantiating VariablesDto and setting the other values that aren't from HttpContext.
IProvideCurrentHttpContext would have a single method that return HttpContext.Current.